# How to block user by country for a specific page in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-redirect

The only way I know is to get the IP of user and check which country is it belong to by using some api at the start of the page from php. And then, redirect it.

So, I'm wondering is there any other better redirection way to do it. Such as from .htaccess?

And is there ways to figure out the country code of the user's ip without 3rd party webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use GeoIP in order to find the IP location and then you can filter an deny the access.

the IP address can be found with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

note: *make sure you read the installation section, cause it's not a default module*

Comment: It is almost perfect solution. Just that i cannot find accurate database. I tried with GeoIp 2 Lite database from maxmind website and I found out it is not accurate. It show an ip as a China ip when it's main database show it as Singapore. So I end up using userinfo.io api. And I have to stick with my initial plans which is using 3rd party api :(

Comment: unfortunately, GeoIP, is never 100% accurate. if you want something accurate you have to use the GPS Coordinates. Most browsers let the users to share their location (but need user to accept). this solution is fast and mostly accurate.